# Issues in creating a domain joined hdinsight cluster

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-hdinsight

Not able to deploy a domain joined Hdinsight cluster
The error that I get is:

Failed to join to domain XXXXXXX.com. Output = Failed to join domain: failed to connect to AD: Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm\n, Error = kerberos_kinit_password XXXXXX@XXXXXXX.ONMICROSOFT.COM failed: Cannot contact any KDC for requested realm\n\"

I have followed the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/domain-joined/apache-domain-joined-configure-using-azure-adds

Created a Hiveuser group in active directory and its a member of AAD DC Administrators

Please help